# Why "It was a secret, of which no one knows." ⇏ "No one of this secret knows."?

Tags: ambiguity

> [2iii] *It was **a secret**, **of which** no one knows.*
> ​= [2iv] No one knows **of this secret**. (**NOT**: No one **of this secret** knows.)

[In his answer](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/70190) above, why did [Damkerng T.](https://ell.stackexchange.com/users/3281/damkerng-t) eliminate

> No one **of this secret** knows.

? Why can't this possibility be deduced from the original pied-piped sentence?

### Analogy

I reckon "No one **of this secret** knows." is one of the possible 2 ambiguities. Why? Just consider this analogous sentence #6!

> 6. It was an **[(frivolous)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_frivolous_political_parties#United_Kingdom) [organization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_organizations_opposing_mainstream_science)**, **`of`** which no one thinks seriously.

This is ambiguous as it can mean 6.1 and/or 6.2.

> 6.1. No member [**`of` this organization**] thinks seriously.

To wit —  all members **`of` this organization** are wacky, and are unable to think rationally.

AND

> 6.2. No one thinks seriously [**`of` this  organization**].

To wit — everyone knows that **this organization** is a joke. But 6.2 says nothing about whether its members are brainy or brainless!

Comment: Your interpretation (6.i) doesn't make sense. To convey that meaning, (6) would have to read _It was a frivolous organisation, no member of which thought seriously_. (If it no longer exists, the members should  be referred to in the past tense.) Neither does _someone of a secret_ make any sense.

Comment: @KateBunting Can you please propose other words that fit this syntax? Please propose a better example?

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking. The original sentence is about **knowing of** a secret (knowing about it) and the two words can't be separated. "no one of a secret" is meaningless.

Comment: @KateBunting What do you think of my analogy?

Comment: Neither sentence is ambiguous, because your supposed 'other meanings' don't make sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no ambiguity.

To 'know of' something means to have knowledge of it. So, *to know of a secret* means you have knowledge of that secret. In modern speech, we are just as likely to say we know '*about*' it.

'Which' is a determiner and a pronoun, so it should be clear what it refers to. In this example, the secret is the subject mentioned from the start, and it's obvious that 'which' is referring back to that.

The sentence could be understood as:

- It was a secret no one knew about.

*or*

- No one knew of the secret.

Sorry to say your analogy just doesn't make any sense. If you think it's ambiguous because you're comparing it with phrases like "*the secret of [x]*" (where [x] is the subject) you're ignoring the fact that there is a comma right after the word 'secret'. Remember that 'which' is used to add extra information to a previous clause, in particular after a comma.

Comment: "Sorry to say your analogy just doesn't make any sense." What do you mean? Sentences 6.1 and 6.2 are felicitous.

Comment: @user they may be grammatically correct sentences but they are in no way possible meanings of the sentence in question.